# React Native app crashes in release version with SIGABRT. [split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libreanimated.so] facebook::jni::JObject::getClass() const

Tags: react-native, crash, expo, react-native-reanimated

## The app freezes and crashes mostly when we relaunch the app from background.

Thread
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_object == null

[image: Google play console crash report]

[image: Crash details]

I thought the react-native-reanimated package is causing the problem. Then I found out that I am not using reanimated anywhere in my project or any other package from node_modules ain't dependant on reanimated. So I uninstalled reanimated. But still this crashes happening.

Comment: Did you try updating your expo package?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem was with the deep-linking library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash was caused by deep-link. The deep-link library for react-native is quite broken

Comment: Hi @Rain I am using React native dynamic link. Is it the issue from this library